# Question about Venn diagrams' role in proofs

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that one needs to show the following results for sets $A$, $B$ and $C$:

(a) $(A\cap B)' = A'\cup B'$

(b) $A\cap (B\cap C)= (A\cap B)\cap C$

where $A'$ is the complement of $A$.

Can he or she work with Venn diagrams for the proofs? Or is it better to talk about illustrations of the results and not about rigorous proofs?

[image]

(Taken from Carol Whitehead: A Guide to Abstract Algrebra)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For straight forward statements believe it or not it’s better to just look at the Venn diagram. For simple statements, Venn diagrams are practically (but not quite) rigorous proof. You can’t use Venn diagrams for more complicated statements, though.

Comment: LHS of (b) is probably meant to be $A\cap(B\cap C)$. I would not call them proofs. Illustration is a better term for it.

Comment: @drhab Thanks for the typo. I corrected. One can be confused easily with \cup and \cap:-)!

Comment: Why do you say "or is it better illustrations.." when even-diagrams are illustrations?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Sorry for the misunderstading. If this was an exercise, could the statement be 'Show/Prove the relations with Venn diagrams' or would be better that the statement say 'Illustrate these results with Venn diagrams'?

Comment: May be it’s better to ask the Question in math educators se

Comment: There are many problems with using Venn diagrams as "proofs". Two in particular are (1) Mathematical proofs derive logically from axioms and definitions. Venn diagrams cannot do this. (2) Sets come in a wide variety of forms. Venn diagrams only represent connected regions in a plane, so anything learned from them is only directly applicable to those regions. To apply it more generally takes an additional argument which is usually ignored. Venn diagrams are great for illustrating a proof, but should not be considered proofs in and of themselves.